# Are html elements with ids already defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming and have a question regarding HTML elements with id attributes.  My question is - if an HTML element has an id attribute, is the value of the id attribute readily usable without defining it in JavaScript?  Here is an example to make this more clear:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" checked />
        <input type="radio" id="myradio" checked />
        <p id="test">
          p tag too.
        </p>

        <script>
          if(mycheckbox.checked) {
            alert("How does this work?  Are there more pre-defined stuff (varaibles?) like this one?");
          }
          if(myradio.checked) {
            alert("Another example with radio");
          }
          alert(test.innerHTML);
        </script>

      </body>
```

I have read some books on JavaScript and none have given this shortcut method (if it is one) of working with HTML elements.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it may works because of backward compatibility for old dark times when ie6 was browser, but its not recommended. use `document.getElementById()` instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: I suggest you to read about [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) to understand the link between HTML and javascript

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to use `document.getElementById(id)` instead. http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Or `$('#id')` if you are using the jQuery library, which I would personally recommend to make things easier for you. To use its methods you just have to include the link to the jQuery script (eg from a CDN) in a  tag

Source: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: This answer is wrong.

Comment: @torazaburo maybe it could still be useful if you pointed out the mistake. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @CyborgFish It's wrong because says "no", but the spec says "yes". See [Named access on the Window object](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object). But `getElementById` is much better practice.

Comment: @Oriol Edited with your info, now it doesnt say "no", but I kept the best practice recommendation. Thanks.